# non-blocking http client vs blocking http client which uses a separated threadpool

Tags: threadpool

What is the difference in terms of performance, resources etc between using a non-blocking http client and a blocking http client which executes on a separated thread-pool. In the latter case the thread will be blocked, but using a separated threadpool reduces the impact on the rest of the app. Is there an actual difference? It would be really helpful if someone could clear this up.

Comment: Generally a well designed app using a Selector will be higher performance, but "well designed" depends on a lot of details which you haven't supplied.

Comment: this is kind of a too broad question for stackoverflow. maybe this helps: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/321529/what-are-the-benefits-of-asynchronous-http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking client will use more resources (mostly because of additional threads - it means more context switches and increased memory usage because of additional stacks). That saying I think that most negative impact can arise from limited number of threads in thread pool - if all threads are blocked with long-running requests then "fast" requests have to wait (even if they are completed).